# python script executes in python interpreter, fails as .py file

Tags: python-3.x, macos-mojave

my script:

```
from os import walk, path, rename

def rename(source, dest):
    for root, sub, files in walk(source):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.mp4'):
                nbase = file.split('.mp4')[0]
                newname = nbase[0:len(nbase) - 12] + '.mp4'

                nsource = path.join(root, file)
                rdest = path.join(dest,newname)

                rename(nsource,rdest)

s = '/Users/ja/Desktop/t'
d = '/Users/ja/Desktop/u'

rename(s,d)
```

This script, line for line, will run in ipython, rename and relocate a file without issue.
when scripted in sublimetext, or in textedit, and saved, it throws no errors, but does nothing.  I am on macOS mojave.

Comment: have you tried a single "print" statement too?

Comment: Yes, I have tried.  Again, total blank.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have given your function the name `rename`, but inside the function you're also trying to use the name `rename` to invoke `os.rename`.  The result is that `os.rename` is never called.  Instead your function makes a recursive call to itself with the old and new filenames as arguments.

That recursive call does nothing because `walk(source)` returns nothing when passed a filename.  The end result is a program that walks the old directory tree correctly but never does anything to the files it finds in that tree.

To fix, give your function a different name that does not clash with `os.rename`.  Maybe something like `rename_in_tree`.  Alternatively, import `os.rename` with a name other than `rename` (`from os import rename as os_rename`) and call it through that new name from inside your function.

I've no idea how this happens to work in `ipython`.  REPL handlers sometimes do strange things with naming scopes, but it seems bizarre that it would somehow call `os.rename` instead of making the recursive call to your function.